# what is the difference between apache cassandra and hbase and mongodb?

Tags: nosql

I have been reading about the NoSQL databases for the last little while and i was just wondering what is the difference about Apache Cassandra and hbase and mongodb?

After i asked a friend he told me that Cassandra is an engine and not a database is that true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They all store data.  Cassandra and HBase are much more like each other; they are both bigtable-like.  Mongodb has a document-oriented storage approach and offers some limited SQL-like capabilities (administratively set indexes, for example).

Cassandra is eventually consistent; whereas HBase is immediately consistent.  HBase requires you to understand a number of server-process roles that must be deployed with care whereas Cassandra nodes are all just 'cassandra' nodes.

If this is all gibberish, good.  Your question is way too huge in scope. Only reading up will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and I will read more thank you so much for the advice